# How do you increase the margin width of a latex document?

Tags: margins, geometry

I am not able to fit my equation onto one line so I want to increase the margin of the page (it looks like it is quite big by default anyway.

Does anyone know how to do this? Here is my template thus far

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

My document full of words and stuff.

\end{document}
```

Comment: have a look at the `geometry` package; I imagine this question is a duplicate of something somewhere though :)

Comment: Instead of widening the margin, you could just try to fit that one equation in otherwise? Here's a solution for that: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75567/4012

Comment: Speaking in general, changing the page shape just because an object doesn't fit doesn't seem a good idea. Shortening the line width will almost surely create problems elsewhere. If you make an example of the offending paragraph, maybe some better advice can come along.

Answer (score 2):

While you might not like the default, there actually was some thought that went into choosing the margins.

From the documentation of [`koma-script`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/)

> The type area defines the size of the printed area of a page and its exact position, the
>   text width depends on the selected font and font size (60–70 characters per line give
>   optimal readability).

So while there are methods to change it, you may want to reconsider. If you don't like the defaults, you might want to consider [`wordlike`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wordlike) package.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He might like the look of the optimally readable default but be forced to use specific margins for school or company work, etc. Suggesting the `wordlike` package is also unnecessary, he didn't say he wants to make it even uglier (IMHO) he just wanted to manually adjust the margins.

Comment: @s0rce, about `worldlike` package in CTAN: "_The package simulates typical word processor layout: narrow page margins, ..._" so this is really an answer to the question. Moreover, as solution to fit an equation could be other that reduce margins,  the recommendation to maintain readable lines is rather appropriate IMHO.

Comment: @s0rce I interpreted "it looks like it is quite big by default anyway" as the OP might be interested in a more word processor like layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the KOMA-bundle (as you do), then the margins should be changed with the `typearea` package, see the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) chapter 2. You can also take a look at [How to reduce the margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32028/how-to-reduce-the-margins) as Werner says.

If you're using the `memmoir` class (like me), then you could take a look in chapter 2 in [memman](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf). The example (section 2.9) should be enough.

If you're using a different document class, then the `geometry` package is (most likely) the way to go.

When you change the layout of the page it's a good idea to know a little about typography. If you're interested you could take a look at [Notes on Book Design](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/memdesign/memdesign.pdf).